# Dominar 250- engine knocking - rainy days

Tags: engine-knock, dominar

I have a dominar 250, covered 20000 kms. Last week I did 5th service. I'm facing engine knocking and bike oftens fails to respond on acceleration on rainy days. Mileage also dropped from 35kmpl to 30kmpl. Previously I used Bajaj's engine oil. Now using motol 10w 40.

Comment: Are you saying that these problems started after you did a service?

Comment: garage uncle suggests to replace air filter and clean throttle body.